# npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL while running npm install

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install

I am facing the error below, I tried clear the cache and install npm latest but all are no use to me, may I know is there any way to resolve it?

```
> npm install
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules\tui-editor\squire-rte@github:seonim-ryu\Squire#fd40b4e3020845825701e9689f190bab3f4775d4" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try to delete node modules folder repeatedly and reinstall packages by `npm install` command
`npm cache clean` try this command after deleted node modules

Comment: but there is no node_modules folder in my project

Comment: try to check your compatibilties with npm and node.js version, do not use current or latest version of node & npm bcuz there may be some issues in there reposetory

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).